# How to sync if model id is hidden field?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to sync data to pivot table for my model. But my `Recipe` model has an hidden `id` field. Like this;

```
protected $hidden = ['id', 'content', 'difficulty_id'];
```

And when I try to sync relationships to pivot table, `recipe_id` becomes zero. If I remove `id` from `$hidden` above, it sync id without any problem. I also tried to call `makeVisible("id")` for the model but didn't help.

```
$changedMeals = $record->meals()->sync($meals);
```

How can I sync `id` when keeping it in `$hidden`?

Thank you very much...

Answer (score 0):

currently, im using pivot with $hidden in primary, and foreign not in pivot, im using `sync($request->field_to_sync)` and im using validator to validate ids, and it worked

eg:

```
class Recipe ... 
{
  protected $hidden = ['id'];

  public function meals(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Pivot::class);
  }
}

class Meals ...
{
  protected $hidden = ['id'];

  public function recipe(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Pivot::class);
  }
}
```

so i assume u are using `sync()` in your code without using `Request::input()`, you can try this :

```
$meals = Meals::select('id')->get()
->map(function($value, $key){
  return $value->setVisible(['id']);
});
```

then u can use `sync()` like this :

```
Recipe::find(1)->meals()->sync($meals);
```